# Chef / performance data

Tags: monitoring, nagios, performance-monitoring, chef

I am looking into making performance data like page response time integrated with Chef. Does anyone has a clue what would be the starting point?

I have already deployed Chef, I have enabled performance data collection, but it doesnt seem to actually collect this data.

Is there any other package, which would be useful in drawing page response time, which is suitable for automated deployment? It doesnt need to be already for Chef, but something useful, or maybe there is some way to get it with the nagios? I have already looked for this with no success. Many thanks!

I would also like to collect the load, network etc. I would prefer to use local agents instead of network.

Comment: Do you mean you want your performance data collected into Chef attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You need performance metrics data collection and trends analysis like charting. chef is for automated configuration and it seems no direct relationship between them.

1. there're lots of tools to track performance metrics. According to web response time, you can refer to the question [Are there any tool for monitoring HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729745/are-there-any-tool-for-monitoring-http-response). If you are using Nginx or Apache httpd, you can try [HttpStabStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule) or [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) and you can google lots of tools around them.
2. you can use lots of metrics collection tool to collect these metric data: [ganglia](http://ganglia.info/), [carbon](http://graphite.wikidot.com/carbon), [collectd](http://collectd.org/), etc, where many of them has built-in default performance metric and you will get them once installed them. They also provide graphing capabilities where you can see time-based trend for each metric.
3. According to chef, there are lots of existing cookbooks to configure the above tools. For local agent, collectd or ganglia would be good candidates.